# On load page is going to first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have created one page where that page contained the menu bar as tabs.

My url is `mydomain.com/UI/ID=2?#about`

Where with respective # the other tabs are there like photo,comment and setting.

When i reload any other tab like `mydomain.com/UI/ID=2?#comment` it going to about tab fraction of seconds then again it will come back to respect comment section.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_content").hide();
    var tabvalue=document.location.hash;
    var activetab=$(this).find("a").attr("href")
    $(".menu_content"+tabvalue).show();
    //$(".menu_content:first").show();
    $("ul.menu li:first").addClass("active");
    $("ul.menu li").click(function() {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 

              $("ul.menu li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".menu_content").hide();

        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
var firstLi  = $("ul.menu li:first").attr('rel');
    if('#' + firstLi !== tabvalue) {
        $("ul.menu li:first").removeClass('active');
        $('li[rel="'+tabvalue.substring(1)+'"]').addClass('active');
    }

});
</script>
```

where menu_content is class name for all tabs.

Can any one guide me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're running this code after the entire page has loaded therefore you're getting a flash while the HTML is rendered in it's default state, and then to the changed version once the code executes.

The nicest way to do this would be to not use a hash for this, rather have the page in the URL i.e. mydomain.com/UI/?ID=2&page=about and use server side code to render it correctly first time, and then update the url using history.pushState in JavaScript.

But if this is all a JavaScript based page, then I would say the easiest way would be to have all of the tabs 'inactive' by default, and then only add the 'active' class when you load the page (either to the hash value, or 'about' by default).

Example:

Style

```
<style type="text/css">
  .menu_content .panel {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //if there's a hash, get it but remove the hash, or use 'about' as a default
    var selectedTab = document.location.hash ? document.location.hash.replace("#", "") : "about";
    $("li#" + selectedTab).addClass("active");
    $("#" + selectedTab + "_panel").show();

    $("ul.menu li").on('click', function() {

      $("ul.menu li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".panel").hide();
      $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_panel").show();

    });

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li id="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li id="comment"><a href="#comment">Comment</a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="menu_content">
  <div id="about_panel" class="panel"></div>
  <div id="comment_panel" class="panel"></div>
  <div id="contact_panel" class="panel"></div>
</div>
```